# Tkinter Date Picker

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am working on a program using Tkinter. I would like to create GUI to select Start date and End date and create a graph based on that. As of now, I just have a simple graph using this code. Attached is my csv file for which I want  to create a graph from start date to end date.For example, I want to create graph from 13th August to 15th August.
Any help is highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEHyA.png)

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

PATH_CSV_FILE = f"Daily Sales\\daywisesale.csv"

data = pandas.read_csv(PATH_CSV_FILE)
plt.plot(data["Date"], data["Price"],color='red',marker='o',linestyle='--')


plt.xlabel("Date of Sale",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Daily Sale Price",fontsize=14)
plt.title("Daily Sales Report Graph")
plt.grid(True,color='b')
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try using two `tkcalendar.DateEntry` for selecting start date and end date and filter the data using the two dates?

Comment: Not tried yet, can you please help me with it.

Comment: Its very easy  to use tkcalendar with tkinter, ill include an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to install `tkcalendar` by saying this, in your terminal:

```
pip install tkcalendar
```

Here is a simple example on tkcalendars `DateEntry`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

root = Tk()

e7 = DateEntry(root, values="Text", year=2020, state="readonly", date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e7.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

You could also use tkcalendars `Calendar`:

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar

e7 = Calendar(root, values="Text", year=2020, state="readonly", date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e7.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

**For your case, you can use two of any of these widgets to get (`e7.selection_get()`) the start date and the end date and then work with it.**

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar#documentation) for more information on the widget

Hope it cleared your doubts, if you have errors, do let me know

Cheers

Comment: _" is not working"_ Any errors? do include it with the Q

Comment: Can you please guide me how to select the dates now from csv file.                                                                                                         e7 = Calendar(root, values="Text", width=12, bg="darkblue",
               fg="white", year=2020, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e7.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)
e8 = Calendar(root, values="Text", width=12, bg="darkblue",
               fg="white", year=2020, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e8.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)
startdate=e7.selection_get()
enddate=e8.selection_get()

Comment: Im afraid that `csv` is not related to this Q(which is around, tkcalendar) why not ask a new Q and someone might help in there, This is so that this answer stays focused around `tkcalendar` and not csv